# Is it right to use “instead of” in this way?

Tags: word-usage

This is an excerpt from AP news article.

Shouldn’t the latter sentence be “She died dehydration instead of the virus”?

**In the end, 59 residents at Gurwin would be killed by the virus, but Best’s mother never contracted it. She died *instead of* dehydration...**

Thank you!

Comment: _Of_ goes with _died_, not _instead_. Your version would have to be "She died _of_ dehydration instead of the virus", but the word _instead_ can be put in other places in the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that sentence should be read as "she died of dehydration", with "instead" as an adverb. It is not an example of the preposition "**instead of**". The sentence could be rearranged like this:
"Instead, she died of dehydration." or
"She died of dehydration instead."

An example where "instead of" is used as a preposition is
"She died of dehydration **instead** of by the virus."

Comment: The "instead of" makes this a "garden path sentence".  If you've parsed it as "instead of" then you have to back up when you hit the word "dehydration".  (You are led "up the garden path) as the expression says)  Good writing avoids garden path sentences as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I got it. Of here goes with die, not instead.